# How to import the excel values in to Selenium IDE

Tags: excel, selenium

I am new to selenium.

Consider that i am having list of values for each time it should take from the excel sheet...

Is there any way we can do it import the excel values in to selenium ide?

if it exists please help me to do this.

If not, which is the best way? How to install Selenium RC?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not. To access Excel files, you will have to extend the IDE's functionality employing Selenium-RC. There is an excellent [article](http://functionaltestautomation.blogspot.com/2009/10/dataprovider-data-driven-testing-with.html) on how to do this.

Comment: Yes you can do this with the "Selblocks" plugin.  Using selblocks with Selenium IDE will allow you to read a XML file and iterate through the values.  It works awesome!

Comment: You can get it from here.  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/